# PHP uploading information into database

Tags: php, sql, image

I am trying to upload some information about an item into a database and upload an image into a folder. I do not receive any errors but the sql query doesn't run and the image is not uploaded either.

```
    <?php

    include'connect.php';

    if( isset($_POST['item_name']) && isset($_POST['description']) && isset($_POST['price']) && isset($_POST['quantity']) && isset($_POST['manufacturer']) &&     isset($_POST['pic']) )
    {
        $name = $_FILES['pic']['name'];
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['pic']['tmp_name'];

    if(!empty($_POST['item_name']) && !empty($_POST['description']) &&  !empty($_POST['price']) && !empty($_POST['quantity']) && !empty($_POST['manufacturer']) &&  !empty($name) )
    {   
        $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
        $description = $_POST['description'];
        $price = $_POST['price'];
        $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
        $manufacturer = $_POST['manufacturer'];

        $location = 'Upload/';
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location.$name);

        $query = "INSERT INTO `item` VALUES ('$item_name', '$description','$price','$quantity','$name','$manufacturer')";

        if($query_run = mysql_query($query))
        {   echo 'Item successfully added.';    }

        else
        {   echo 'Query Failure';   }


    }
}

?>

<form  action = 'additems.php' method = 'POST' enctype = 'multipart/form-data' >
    Name: <input type = 'text' name = 'item_name' ><br><br>
    Description: <input type = 'text' name = 'description' ><br><br>
    Price: <input type = 'text' name = 'price' ><br><br>
    Quantity: <input type = 'text' name = 'quantity' ><br><br>
    Manufacturer: <select name = 'manufacturer' >
                  <option value = '1'> Manufacturer 1 </option>
                  <option value = '2'> Manufacturer 2 </option>
                  <option value = '3'> Manufacturer 3 </option>
                  <option value = '4'> Manufacturer 4 </option>
                  </select>
                  <br><br>
    Picture: <input type = 'file' name = 'pic' > <br><br>

    <input type = 'submit' value = 'Submit' >

</form>
```

I have a manufacturer table with 4 entries. ids ranging from 1-4.
the connect.php file connects me to the database and I can confirm it has no errors.

Comment: does it output at least something? 'Query failure' from your echo i.e.?

Comment: Yes, the echo error is outputted.

Comment: As said: post your mysql error message

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 isset($_POST['pic'])
```

to

```
 isset($_FILE['pic']['name'])
```

Comment: Yep, it worked. Now my 'query failure' error popped up. Just need to fix my query.

Comment: I meant the one from my echo statement.